# cakephp 3 response withFile and video tag

Tags: php, google-chrome, cakephp, html5-video, cakephp-3.x

I've used this code to send a video using an action in CakePHP:

```
$response = $this->response->withFile(WWW_ROOT.'Component.webm',['download' => false]);
```

and inside template:

```
        <video class="img-responsive" controls>
        <source src="<?= Router::url(['controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'stream', $id]) ?>" />
    </video>
```

everything works great in Microsoft Edge. But when I view the page inside Google Chrome and I start playing the video I cannot visit any other page of my site, until the video is downloaded completely, and after 30 seconds, if the video is not downloaded this error is shown:

```
Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem here:
https://gist.github.com/ranacseruet/9826293#gistcomment-2141349

I used `session_write_close();` on top of my action and now chrome works too.