# PHP Download script not able to navigate to other page until Download finishes

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm working on a video based website, I have to give the link to download video.

I used the below code and it is working fine.

```
if (file_exists($FileDownload)) {
        $Basename = pathinfo($FileDownload, PATHINFO_BASENAME);

        $mime = 'application/force-download';
        header('Pragma: public');  // required
        header('Expires: 0');  // no cache
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Cache-Control: private', false);
        header('Content-Type: ' . $mime);
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($Basename) . '"');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Connection: close');
        readfile("$FileDownload");  // push it out
        exit();
    }
$this->render(false);
```

it is forcefully downloading the file, It is written on my Controller action and i make the view render false.

Issue is when i click on download and file started downloading, i'm not able to navigate to other pages until the download finishes.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you expect to be able to do that

Comment: Sounds like **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50195449/cakephp-3-response-withfile-and-video-tag/50195625**. Also controllers should never echo data! Refer to the cookbook matching your CakePHP version on how to send files.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast reply, My video size is huge in MB (200) so it takes time to download. so, i'm not able to do anything on my website if i click to some other link to visit it keeps loading not navigating me to other page until the download finishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot's of efforts finally I got to know the answer.

CakePhp response file is the solution of my problem.

updated code

```
$FileDownload = base64_decode($FileDownload);


        // Retrieve the file ready for download

        $Basename = pathinfo($FileDownload, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
        // Run any pre-download logic here.
        // Send file as response
        $this->response->file(
                $FileDownload, array(
            'download' => true,
            'name' => $Basename
                )
        );
        return $this->response;
```